# Please Help! Maximum call stack size exceeded with Firebase and Vuex

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, nuxt.js, vuex

**Context**

I am creating a basic pagination feature with only forward and back buttons. I am using firebase, nuxt js and vuex. On initial load, the store is dispatches the getPosts function in vuex. This function fills the post state and the last post so I can use it as a reference when I need to load more post.

**Problem**
The `lastVisiblePost` variable is a complex firebase object (snapshots.docs) and calls a stack size exceed error when I try to add it to the store. The weird part is that it only does this when I refresh the page. The code works perfectly when it's only running on the client. Can anyone please help me figure this out?

**Fail Attempts**

- Checked typeof which it's an object
- Turn `lastVisiblePost` to JSON (throws  starting at object with constructor 'FirebaseAppImpl' | property 'firebase_' -> object with constructor 'Object' | property 'apps' -> object with constructor 'Array')
- Used a copy of `lastVisiblePost`
- disable strict mode

**Code**

*Local*

```
<template>
    <button @click="loadMorePosts({ paginationDirection: 'next' })">Next</button>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
        async fetch() {
            await this.$store.dispatch('post/getPosts');
        },

        methods: {
            loadMorePosts({ paginationDirection }) {
                this.$store.dispatch('post/getMorePosts', { paginationDirection });
            },
        },
    };
</script>
```

*Vuex*

```
import { db } from '~/plugins/firebase';

export const state = () => ({
   posts: null,
   pagination: {
       postsPerPage: 3,
       lastVisiblePost: null,
   },
});

export const actions = {
   async getPosts({ commit, state }) {
       const snapshots = await db.collection('posts').limit(state.pagination.postsPerPage).get();

       if (snapshots.docs.length === 0) { return []; }

       const posts = snapshots.docs.map((doc) => ({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id }));

       const firebasePosts = snapshots.docs;
       const lastIndex = firebasePosts.length - 1;
       const lastVisiblePost = firebasePosts[lastIndex];

       commit('SET_POSTS', posts);
       commit('SET_LAST_VISIBLE_POST', lastVisiblePost);
   },
 
 async getMorePosts({ commit, state }, { paginationDirection }) {
       if (state.pagination.isFetchingData) {  return; }

   let query;
   
       if (paginationDirection === 'next') {
           query = db.collection('posts').startAfter(state.pagination.lastVisiblePost).limit(state.pagination.postsPerPage);
       }

   const snapshots = await query.get();
   
       if (snapshots.docs.length === 0) {  return [];  }

       const posts = snapshots.docs.map((doc) => ({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id }));

       const firebasePosts = snapshots.docs;
       const lastIndex = firebasePosts.length - 1;
       const lastVisiblePost = firebasePosts[lastIndex];

       commit('SET_POSTS', posts);
       commit('SET_LAST_VISIBLE_POST', lastVisiblePost);

       if (paginationDirection === 'next') {
           commit('SET_PREVIOUS_FIRST_POST', firebasePosts[0]);
       }
   },
};

export const mutations = {
   SET_POSTS(state, posts) {
       state.posts = posts;
   },
   SET_LAST_VISIBLE_POST(state, lastVisiblePost) {
       // Problem happens here
       state.pagination.lastVisiblePost = lastVisiblePost;
   },
};
```